# Connectedness question

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

In pugh's analysis, one example was like this.

"The union of two disjoint closed intervals is not homeomorphic to a single interval. One set is disconnected and the other is connected."

Can't understand this one. Is it telling that union is disconnected ? How ?

Comment: That exact what it is saying.  $[0,1] \cup [2,3] \ne (a,b); [0,1] \cup [2,3] \ne [a,b];[0,1] \cup [2,3] \ne (a,b]; [0,1] \cup [2,3] \ne [a,b)$ for any $a $ and $b$.  $[0,1]\cup [2,3]$ is disconnected.  (a,b), (a,b], [a,b) and [a,b] are all connected.

Comment: @fleablood I got that but I want to know how that union is disconnected ? In pugh's analysis, definition of disconnected sets : If set is disconnected then there should be seperation of set in proper, disjoint clopen subsets.   How this definition imply that union is disconnected ?

Comment: That definition is wrong (did you perhaps misread it?). A set is disconnected if there is a separation of the set into proper, disjoint **open** subsets, which is exactly what is verified in the answer of @KajHansen.

Comment: @LeeMosher In Pugh's analysis, instead of open sets, clopen sets are taken in definition and whole theory is developed on it. We can also prove that for asked example : both sets are closed in their union(obvious), their complement in their union is open, so both sets are open also in their union. So both intervals are clopen in their union.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it telling that union is disconnected?

Yes indeed.  Given real numbers $w<x<y<z$, consider the space $A = [w,x] \cup [y,z]$.  The open sets in $A$ are defined per the [subspace topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Subspace_topology#Definition) inherited from $\mathbb{R}$; that is, a subset $U \subset A$ is open $\iff$ we can write $U = U' \cap \mathbb{R}$ for some open $U' \subset \mathbb{R}$.

Further, we say a topological space is disconnected if it can be expressed as the union of two disjoint open sets.  In this scenario, notice we can find numbers $a, b, c $ such that we have $a< [w,x] < b < [y,z] < c$.  Certainly the open sets $(a,b)$ and $(b,c)$ in $\mathbb{R}$ are disjoint, and $(a,b) \cap A = [w,x]$ and $(b,c) \cap A = [y,z]$.  Therefore, $A$ is disconnected because it can be expressed as the union of two disjoint open sets, namely $[w,x]$ and $[y,z]$.

P.S. also consider why intervals $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ are connected.  Intuitive?  Sure.  Easily justified?

Comment: Understood. I was unaware of this subspace topology. Well proved. Can we prove it disconnected by showing the set to be union of proper, disjoint clopen subsets ?

Comment: That is more-or-less what we've done here @MeetRayvadera, but you're touching close to a related idea: one can show that a topological space is disconnected $\iff$ we can find a clopen subset other than the empty set or the whole space itself.  Certainly in this example, both $[w,x]$ and $[y,z]$ are clopen in $A$.

Comment: I got it. We can take complement of one interval in A and can say that other interval is open in A. Thanks..